# Eigenvalues of matrix of order $n+1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How to find eigenvalues of following matrix?

$A=\begin{bmatrix} n & -1 & -1 & \cdots & -1 \\
-1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}_{n+1}$

The answer is $1(n-1 \; \text{times})$,$n+1$,$0$.

But how to find it by applying suitable row(column) transformation  on $det(A-\lambda I)$

Comment: Row/column transformation are in general not a valid way to compute eigenvalues, since such transformations change the eigenvalues of a matrix.

Comment: ok then what is the other way?

Comment: First, the $n-1$ last columns are equal so without any computation, 0 is an eigenvalue of multiplicity $\geq n-2$ because $C_3-C_4,C_3-C_5...$ are eigenvectors for 0 (i.e. elements of the kernel of your matrix).

Comment: Also, it is clear that your answer is wrong since this is a rank $2$ matrix, so it can't have $0$ as an eigenvector $n$ times.

Comment: oh ok so what should be the answer

Comment: I had edited my question

Comment: actually, you may yet be right.  In any case, my answer will be up in a bit

Comment: you could work out the determinant $det(A-\lambda I)$ from the right by unwinding the rows and not the columns.

Comment: Wait... you just changed the question from having the ones be in the second column to being along the diagonal.  This completely changes the answer.  Which problem did you want answered?

Comment: now the question and answers are correct

Comment: I apology for my mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to find the eigenvalues: we observe that $A - I$ is a symmetric rank $2$ matrix, so it has exactly $2$ non-zero eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$, and it has $0$ as an eigenvalue exactly $n-1$ times.

We note that
$$
\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = \operatorname{trace}(A-I) = n-1\\
\lambda_1^2 + \lambda_2^2 = \operatorname{trace}((A-I)^2) = (n-1)^2 + 2n = n^2 +1
$$
We could solve these equations for $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ to find that we must have $\lambda_1 = -1$ and $\lambda_2 = n$.

Now, since we have the eigenvalues of $A - I$, we may conclude that the eigenvalues of $A$ are indeed $n+1,0,$ and $1$ ($n-1$ times).

Comment: You could also find the eigenvalues by performing row operations on $A - \lambda I$.  However, I like this way better.